# C# JSON Error (Error converting value "username" to type)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get a JSON reply instagram and "Serializing Partial JSON Fragments".

It JSON reply

```
{
  "access_token": "Here token",
  "user": {
    "username": "here user name",
    "bio": "her bio.",
    "website": "her website",
    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/here picture",
    "full_name": "her name",
    "id": "and her id"
  }
}
```

I created a class User:

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
}
```

And serializing

```
JObject instaCall = JObject.Parse(responseString);
            IList<JToken> results = instaCall["user"].Children().ToList();
            foreach (JToken apiResult in results)
            {
                User searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(apiResult.ToString());
            }
```

And gives me an error:

> Error converting value "username" to type
>   'WpfApplication1.Control.BasicPage1+User'. Path '', line 1, position
>   10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you don't need to loop to get to the json you're trying to deserialize.  Another way to convert just the user object from the json:

```
JObject instaCall = JObject.Parse(responseString);    
User searchResult = instaCall["user"].ToObject<User>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to be looping through a list to get the object out if that is your response string.

```
User searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(instaCall["user"].ToString());
```

**Edit**

If it would work, I would probably make a response object to handle the deserialization cleaner.

```
public class Response
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; } //your existing class
}
```

Then do

```
Response searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>("whole Response");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're looping through the children of the "user" object. So, you end up trying to cast each child object ("username", "bio", etc.) as a User.